# how to update a field which contains data using mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to update a field which contains data.

**For ex:**

```
id     fieldName
1         1,2
```

Now, I am getting 3,4 as another result which should be updated in id 1. That is now my result should be,

```
id     fieldName
1       1,2,3,4
```

How can this be done using mysql.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update TableName set fieldName = CONCAT(fieldName, '3,4') where id = 1;
```

Comment: @Fero: Cool, but set some answer as accepter to remove it from unanswered section ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Following should do the trick:

UPDATE tablename SET columnname=concat(columnname,' my extra text');

Comment: Sorry by the time I added similar answer was already posted :(.

Answer (score -1):

By using [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) of course:

```
 UPDATE TABLENAME
 SET fieldName = "1,2,3,4"
 WHERE id = 1;
```

Assuming that fieldName is a string.